# Is it a general rule to use a noun as uncountable when generally referring to the type of things?

Tags: grammar

Per [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/speech), in the meaning of formal talk, the word "speech" could be either uncountable or countable.

In a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/cFuCbi44gGk?t=524), the speaker says

> However this is unconventional and I suggest you  do use a subjunctive especially in formal speech and in writing.

where, the word "speech" is used as uncountable.

Is it a general rule/practice to use a noun as uncountable when generally referring to the type of things, if the noun could be either uncountable or countable?

Comment: "Speech" has two distinct meanings. In your example, it is a non-count noun meaning the act of speaking.  But in, for example, "He gave two speeches while visiting" it is a count noun meaning individual talks, which can be counted.

Comment: In OP's cited context, plural *...especially in formal **speeches*** would be perfectly valid (if *unlikely*). That would specifically refer to the context of "formal vocal addresses" as mentioned by @Billj, which isn't at all the same thing as singular ***speech*** (a generic reference to the more abstract process of communication by speaking). Much the same distinction apply to ***writing*** (generic reference to ***all*** written texts, including stuff like a shopping list or note for the milkman) and ***writings*** (formal written academic / literary texts - essays, books, etc.).